# Is there a way to kill an activity when PendingIntent is fired?

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In Android to kill an activity, you just use `finish()`. But in my case I want to kill the activity when the `PendingIntent` is fired.

My code is as follow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, recordLength);

PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,
        piNumber, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

If I add `finish()` beneath, the activity will be killed before the time set up in the `AlarmManager`.

I want the activity to be visible until the time goes off and kill it. Are there any ways to do this? I did some searches in Stack Overflow, Google but could not find an answer.

Comment: Explain what your `Activity` does. You probably shouldn't be using `AlarmManager` and you also don't have any control over the user finishing the `Activity` using the `BACK` button anyway.

Comment: If you want to finish your activity at a particular time please do call a timer task.And call finish inside it.

Comment: @Squonk I have to capture videos at specific times( eg. 12h00, 13h00, 15h00, ...) . When the app captures the video 2 minutes I want it back to the preview activity(MainActivity.java). I was reluctant to use AlarmManager first but after days and days researching I realize I did not have any other choice. If you know a better way please share.

Comment: @SREEJITH thanks! Thats one way I did not think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a timer you get the time delay of the pending intent.

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
},pending intent delay);
```

Please try this.It work for me

Comment: What is cal.getTimeInMillis() in your alarm.set method ?

Comment: I figured it out after asking the silly question. I am trying your solution now.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) dynamically in your activity. With the pending intent, you use [`getBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29). So you can call `finish()` inside the broadcast receiver when it is invoked by the alarm manager. Note that you *must* unregister the receiver when you don't need it anymore, you do that in `onDestroy()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`onNewIntent(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29). If you can start your activity as a single top, then your instance should receive the pending intent through that call.

If you can't use singel top, and a new instance of your activity is being launched, you could use a shared static to get the original instance in `onCreate()` of the new one and `finish()` both.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that setting to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is doing for job.

Comment: Okay after some test I find out that FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP doesnt clear the activities in the stack.